# How to add arrow heads in path in mapdeck

Tags: r, deck.gl, mapdeck

I am trying to plot a path from a dataframe of lat lon coordinates. The data can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SV0vCrE9CZUSVa_5tqLKCTfWlB6Siry-). This is the code I am using for plotting the path:

```
library(sf)
library(mapdeck)
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat")) %>% 
  group_by(imoNumber) %>%summarise(m=mean(imoNumber, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% st_cast("LINESTRING")
mapdeck(token = key, style = mapdeck_style("outdoors")) %>% 
  add_path(data = df1)
```

This plots the data like this:

[image]

Is there some way of adding arrow heads to show the direction of the path? Something akin to polyline decorator in leaflet? Desired result is something like this:

[image]

Comment: This is not currently possible in mapdeck.

Comment: @SymbolixAU would be nice if you could add this whenever time permits. In the interim, do you have any suggestion for overcoming the problem of loading a very large number of line segments in leaflet in a Shiny app? That's why I was looking at mapdeck, but now can't because of the path direction problem.

Comment: If you can convince the [deck.gl](https://github.com/uber/deck.gl) developers to add it as a feature then I'll be able to add it in to mapdeck quite easily. But at the moment I'm unlikely to get round to doing this myself

Comment: I've added this to my issue tracker as a feature request - https://github.com/SymbolixAU/mapdeck/issues/146 , but, I won't be working on it anytime soon

Comment: @SymbolixAU thanks, will wait for this feature.

Comment: not arrow heads, but you can now use dashed lines - example on [twitter](https://twitter.com/_davecooley/status/1172770171804479488)